# Publishing NopCommerce Issue

Tags: publish, nopcommerce

I've got a nopCommerce project. I could publish it successfully to a server from my local but it took about 1,5 hours to upload complete ( depending my upload speed ).

**Question:** Is there a way to sync or update files which i only modify inside VS  than uploading whole published project? (cause I told above it took much time for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to publish whole project on deployment server at the very first time, afterwords there is no need of publish a whole project *again* and *again*.

> Is there a way to sync or update files which i only modify inside VS than uploading whole published project?

There are many [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) tools [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_version_control_software) to track your file changes. You can  use it and update only required files and DLLs.

Comment: Thank you i'll try that asap